# Show error note if image not selected android

Tags: java, android, dialog, gallery

This is my full code below. am coding an android app that can select image from gallery or any where and upload it to Mysql server through php but if image is not selected and the upload button is press the application crashes so i want to implement the function that it shows error dialog / warning dialog if image is not selected from gallery have already implemented it in EditText but cannot implement it in Image. below is my code

```
package com.app.markeet;



public class ActivityPost extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonUpload;
    private Button buttonChoose;

    EditText editTitle, editTextPrice, editTextDescription, editTextStatus, editTextAuthorsname, editTextAuthorsphone;
    private ImageView imageView,choiceItemImg,choiceItemImg2,choiceItemImg3,choiceItemImg4;

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "name";
    public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
    public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    public static final String KEY_STOCK = "stock";
    public static final String KEY_AUTHORSNAME = "authorsname";
    public static final String KEY_AUTHORSPHONE = "authorsphone";
    public static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.0.199/config/upload.php";
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    public static final int CREATE_POST_IMG = 5;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Uri outputFileUri;
    public static final int SELECT_POST_IMG = 3;
    public static final String APP_TEMP_FOLDER = "kobobay";

    String[] categories = { "Animals and Pets", "Electronics and Video",
            "Fashion and Beauty", "Home,  Furniture  and Garden", "Mobile  Phone  and Tablets", "PC, Laptop and Accessories",
            "Jobs and Services", "Real Estate and Roommate", "Hobbles, Art and Sport", "Books and Tutorial",
            "Vehicles", "Other"};
    int[] catevalue = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

    Spinner spinner1;
    TextView textView1;

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    private String selectedPostImg = "";
    ImageView mChoiceItemImg, mLocationDelete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("");

        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChooseImage);

        editTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
        editTextPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPrice);
        editTextDescription = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDescription);
        editTextStatus = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editStatus);
        editTextAuthorsname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
        editTextAuthorsphone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityPost.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);

        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);

        choiceItemImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.choiceItemImg);
        choiceItemImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showFileChooser();
            }
        });

        mChoiceItemImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.choiceItemImg2);

        mChoiceItemImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (selectedPostImg.length() == 0) {

                    imageFromGallery();

                } else {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityPost.this);
                    alertDialog.setTitle(getText(R.string.action_remove));

                    alertDialog.setMessage(getText(R.string.label_delete_img));
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);

                    alertDialog.setNeutralButton(getText(R.string.action_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getText(R.string.action_remove), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            mChoiceItemImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_camera);
                            selectedPostImg = "";
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });

        String URL = Constant.WEB_URL + "get/user_info.php";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse= new JSONObject(response);
                            //txtName.setText(jsonResponse.getString("fullname"));
                            editTextAuthorsname.setText(jsonResponse.getString("login"));
                            //txtEmail.setText(jsonResponse.getString("email"));
                            editTextAuthorsphone.setText(jsonResponse.getString("phone"));// you need to create this textView txtPoints.
                        } catch (Throwable t) {
                            Log.e("onResponse", "The response: " + response + " seems to not be json formatted.");
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivityPost.this,error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username",ThisApplication.getInstance().getUsername());
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 =
            new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                           int position, long id) {
                    String s1 = String.valueOf(catevalue[position]);
                    textView1.setText(s1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

            };

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }


    public void imageFromGallery() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getText(R.string.label_select_img)), SELECT_POST_IMG);
    }

    public void imageFromCamera() {

        try {

            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), APP_TEMP_FOLDER);

            if (!root.exists()) {

                root.mkdirs();
            }

            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "post.jpg");
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CREATE_POST_IMG);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Toast.makeText(ActivityPost.this, "Error occured. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                choiceItemImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == SELECT_POST_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                choiceItemImg2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }


    public void uploadImage(){
        final String GetAuthorsname = editTextAuthorsname.getText().toString();
        final String GetAuthorsphone = editTextAuthorsphone.getText().toString();
        final String GetTitle = editTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        final String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
        final String GetPrice = editTextPrice.getText().toString();
        final String GetStock = textView1.getText().toString();
        final String GetDescription = editTextDescription.getText().toString();
        final String GetStatus = editTextStatus.getText().toString();

        class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityPost.this,"Please wait...","uploading",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(ActivityPost.this,s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();
                param.put(KEY_TITLE,GetTitle);
                param.put(KEY_IMAGE,image);
                param.put(KEY_PRICE,GetPrice);
                param.put(KEY_STOCK,GetStock);
                param.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION,GetDescription);
                param.put(KEY_STATUS,GetStatus);
                param.put(KEY_AUTHORSNAME,GetAuthorsname);
                param.put(KEY_AUTHORSPHONE,GetAuthorsphone);
                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, param);
                return result;
            }
        }
        UploadImage u = new UploadImage();
        u.execute();
    }

    public Boolean checkPicture() {

        String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

        String GetPrice = editTextPrice.getText().toString();
        String GetDescription = editTextDescription.getText().toString();
        String GetStatus = editTextStatus.getText().toString();

        editTitle.setError(null);
        editTextPrice.setError(null);
        editTextDescription.setError(null);
        editTextStatus.setError(null);


        if (image.length() == 0) {

            editTitle.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

            return false;

        } if (GetPrice.length() == 0) {

            editTextPrice.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));
            return false;

        } if (GetDescription.length() == 0) {

            editTextDescription.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

            return false;

        } if (GetStatus.length() == 0) {

            editTextStatus.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

            return false;
        }

        return  true;
    }

    public Boolean checkDesc() {

        String GetDescription = editTextDescription.getText().toString();
        editTextDescription.setError(null);

        if (GetDescription.length() == 0) {

            editTextDescription.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

            return false;
        }

        return  true;
    }

    public Boolean checkProductName() {

        String GetTitle = editTitle.getText().toString();

        editTitle.setError(null);

        if (GetTitle.length() == 0) {

            editTitle.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

            return false;
        }

        return  true;
    }

    public Boolean checkCategory() {

        String GetStock = textView1.getText().toString();

        textView1.setError(null);

        if (GetStock.length() == 0) {

            editTitle.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

            return false;
        }

        return  true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonChoose){
            showFileChooser();
            //imageFromGallery();
        }
        if(v == buttonUpload){

            // checkUsername();
            if (!ThisApplication.getInstance().isConnected()) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.msg_network_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (!checkProductName() || !checkDesc() || !checkCategory()) {


            } else {

                uploadImage();
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_item, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.sync:
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_post:
                uploadImage();
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello can some one help me with my question

Comment: the problem is in here this line is for image String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap); and this is for text final String GetTitle = editTitle.getText().toString().trim();  so how will i make image work

Answer (score 0):

Just copy this code and paste

```
package com.app.markeet;



public class ActivityPost extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button buttonUpload;
private Button buttonChoose;

EditText editTitle, editTextPrice, editTextDescription, editTextStatus, editTextAuthorsname, editTextAuthorsphone;
private ImageView imageView,choiceItemImg,choiceItemImg2,choiceItemImg3,choiceItemImg4;

public static final String KEY_TITLE = "name";
public static final String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String KEY_STOCK = "stock";
public static final String KEY_AUTHORSNAME = "authorsname";
public static final String KEY_AUTHORSPHONE = "authorsphone";
public static final String KEY_STATUS = "status";
public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.0.199/config/upload.php";
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
public static final int CREATE_POST_IMG = 5;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Uri outputFileUri;
public static final int SELECT_POST_IMG = 3;
public static final String APP_TEMP_FOLDER = "kobobay";

String[] categories = { "Animals and Pets", "Electronics and Video",
        "Fashion and Beauty", "Home,  Furniture  and Garden", "Mobile  Phone  and Tablets", "PC, Laptop and Accessories",
        "Jobs and Services", "Real Estate and Roommate", "Hobbles, Art and Sport", "Books and Tutorial",
        "Vehicles", "Other"};
int[] catevalue = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

Spinner spinner1;
TextView textView1;

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ActionBar actionBar;

private String selectedPostImg = "";
ImageView mChoiceItemImg, mLocationDelete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("");

    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChooseImage);

    editTitle = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
    editTextPrice = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPrice);
    editTextDescription = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDescription);
    editTextStatus = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editStatus);
    editTextAuthorsname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    editTextAuthorsphone = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editPhone);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(ActivityPost.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener1);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);

    choiceItemImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.choiceItemImg);
    choiceItemImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showFileChooser();
        }
    });

    mChoiceItemImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.choiceItemImg2);

    mChoiceItemImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (selectedPostImg.length() == 0) {

                imageFromGallery();

            } else {

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityPost.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle(getText(R.string.action_remove));

                alertDialog.setMessage(getText(R.string.label_delete_img));
                alertDialog.setCancelable(true);

                alertDialog.setNeutralButton(getText(R.string.action_cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.setPositiveButton(getText(R.string.action_remove), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        mChoiceItemImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_camera);
                        selectedPostImg = "";
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    });

    String URL = Constant.WEB_URL + "get/user_info.php";

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonResponse= new JSONObject(response);
                        //txtName.setText(jsonResponse.getString("fullname"));
                        editTextAuthorsname.setText(jsonResponse.getString("login"));
                        //txtEmail.setText(jsonResponse.getString("email"));
                        editTextAuthorsphone.setText(jsonResponse.getString("phone"));// you need to create this textView txtPoints.
                    } catch (Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("onResponse", "The response: " + response + " seems to not be json formatted.");
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityPost.this,error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username",ThisApplication.getInstance().getUsername());
            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

}

AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener1 =
        new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                String s1 = String.valueOf(catevalue[position]);
                textView1.setText(s1);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

        };

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}


public void imageFromGallery() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getText(R.string.label_select_img)), SELECT_POST_IMG);
}

public void imageFromCamera() {

    try {

        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), APP_TEMP_FOLDER);

        if (!root.exists()) {

            root.mkdirs();
        }

        File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "post.jpg");
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CREATE_POST_IMG);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(ActivityPost.this, "Error occured. Please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            choiceItemImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == SELECT_POST_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            choiceItemImg2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}


public void uploadImage(){
    final String GetAuthorsname = editTextAuthorsname.getText().toString();
    final String GetAuthorsphone = editTextAuthorsphone.getText().toString();
    final String GetTitle = editTitle.getText().toString().trim();
    final String image = getStringImage(bitmap);
    final String GetPrice = editTextPrice.getText().toString();
    final String GetStock = textView1.getText().toString();
    final String GetDescription = editTextDescription.getText().toString();
    final String GetStatus = editTextStatus.getText().toString();

    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
        ProgressDialog loading;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(ActivityPost.this,"Please wait...","uploading",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ActivityPost.this,s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
            HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();
            param.put(KEY_TITLE,GetTitle);
            param.put(KEY_IMAGE,image);
            param.put(KEY_PRICE,GetPrice);
            param.put(KEY_STOCK,GetStock);
            param.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION,GetDescription);
            param.put(KEY_STATUS,GetStatus);
            param.put(KEY_AUTHORSNAME,GetAuthorsname);
            param.put(KEY_AUTHORSPHONE,GetAuthorsphone);
            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL, param);
            return result;
        }
    }
    UploadImage u = new UploadImage();
    u.execute();
}

public Boolean checkPicture() {

    String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

    String GetPrice = editTextPrice.getText().toString();
    String GetDescription = editTextDescription.getText().toString();
    String GetStatus = editTextStatus.getText().toString();

    editTitle.setError(null);
    editTextPrice.setError(null);
    editTextDescription.setError(null);
    editTextStatus.setError(null);


    if (image.length() == 0) {

        editTitle.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

        return false;

    } if (GetPrice.length() == 0) {

        editTextPrice.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));
        return false;

    } if (GetDescription.length() == 0) {

        editTextDescription.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

        return false;

    } if (GetStatus.length() == 0) {

        editTextStatus.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

        return false;
    }

    return  true;
}

public Boolean checkDesc() {

    String GetDescription = editTextDescription.getText().toString();
    editTextDescription.setError(null);

    if (GetDescription.length() == 0) {

        editTextDescription.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

        return false;
    }

    return  true;
}

public Boolean checkProductName() {

    String GetTitle = editTitle.getText().toString();

    editTitle.setError(null);

    if (GetTitle.length() == 0) {

        editTitle.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

        return false;
    }

    return  true;
}

public Boolean checkCategory() {

    String GetStock = textView1.getText().toString();

    textView1.setError(null);

    if (GetStock.length() == 0) {

        editTitle.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_empty));

        return false;
    }

    return  true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v == buttonChoose){
        showFileChooser();
        //imageFromGallery();
    }
    if(v == buttonUpload){

        // checkUsername();
        if (!ThisApplication.getInstance().isConnected()) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.msg_network_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (!checkProductName() || !checkDesc() || !checkCategory()) {


        } else {

            uploadImage();
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    finish();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_item, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.sync:
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_post:
            uploadImage();
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}